# jQuery validate allowing username

Tags: jquery

How do I set these usernames "Webmaster, Admin, Administrator or .." to not allowed for register?

I've tried this.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notallowedusername", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || 
        element.value == 'webmaster, admin';
}, 'This username is not allowed!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for each username individually. Try this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notallowedusername", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.value !== 'webmaster' && element.value !== 'admin' && element.value !== 'administrator');
}, 'This username is not allowed!');
```

You may want to make this case insensitive too, by using `.toLowerCase()` on the `value` before you use it in the conditions.